# Extract Headers From HTTP Request In Perl

Tags: perl, header

I want to read headers in http or https request in my perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = "http://example.com/";
my $req = $ua->get("$url");
```

I want To Extract The Headers Data Of The Upper Request Such As :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, content-type, content-length
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 01:43:01 GMT
Etag: "779429019"
Cookie: username=usrname; pass=P@S$W0RD;
X-Powered-By: adzerk bifrost/
x-served-by: engine-i-536776c8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your `$req` is actually a *response* object, not a request

To examine all of the header fields, you are looking for `$resp->headers_as_string`

To generate the output that you show, you would write this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = 'http://example.com/';

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

print $resp->protocol, ' ', $resp->status_line, "\n";
print $resp->headers_as_string, "\n";
```

Comment: The question asks for **request** headers, not **response** headers.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missunderstanding something, I dont see your problem. 
You are already using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) which states that `->get` returns a [HTTP::Respnse](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object on which you can call `->header` to get at header fields as documented [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers).

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = "http://github.com/";
my $res = $ua->get("$url");

say "Headers returned: ", join(", ", $res->header_field_names);
say "With values:" ;
say "  $_: ", $res->header($_) for  $res->header_field_names ;

# Outputs

# Headers returned: Content-Type, Client-Date, Client-Warning
# With values:
#   Content-Type: text/plain
#   Client-Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 02:31:26 GMT
#   Client-Warning: Internal response
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $result = $ua->get("http://example.com/");
print $result;
print "HTTP code: ".$result->code;
```

`$result` will be no plain text response, but a [HTTP::Response object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Response). The output of the above script is:

```
HTTP::Response=HASH(0x23dbfc8)
HTTP code: 200
```

This object has methods (like `->code` to get the HTTP status code). The documentation states (shortened):

> $r->header( $field )
>
> This is used to get header values and it is inherited from
>   [HTTP::Headers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Headers) via [HTTP::Message](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Message). See [HTTP::Headers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Headers) for details and
>   other similar methods that can be used to access the headers.

`HTTP::Headers` itself has a method `header_field_names`:

> $h->header_field_names
>
> Returns the list of distinct names for the fields present in the
>   header. The field names have case as suggested by HTTP spec, and the
>   names are returned in the recommended "Good Practice" order.
>
> In scalar context return the number of distinct field names.

Your script could easily get the requested information:

```
for my $header_name ($result->header_field_names) {
    print $header_name.": ".$result->header($header_name);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:40:52 GMT
ETag: "359670651+ident"
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1270
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Thu, 05 May 2016 05:40:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Client-Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:40:52 GMT
Client-Peer: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Title: Example Domain
X-Cache: HIT
X-Ec-Custom-Error: 1
X-Meta-Charset: utf-8
X-Meta-Viewport: width=device-width, initial-scale=1
```

`$result->header($header_name)` is also useful to get one header value for a known header name. Let's say out want to have the ETag of the response:

```
print $result->header('ETag');
```

`HTTP::Headers` also has a `->as_string` method, but it's overwritten by the `->as_string` method from `HTTP::Response`. But `HTTP::Message` has two solutions:

> $mess->headers
>
> Returns the embedded HTTP::Headers object.

You could walk though the objects to get the HTTP headers as one string by doing

```
print $result->headers->as_string;
```

which outputs:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:47:54 GMT
ETag: "359670651+ident"
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1270
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Thu, 05 May 2016 05:47:54 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Client-Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:47:54 GMT
Client-Peer: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Title: Example Domain
X-Cache: HIT
X-Ec-Custom-Error: 1
X-Meta-Charset: utf-8
X-Meta-Viewport: width=device-width, initial-scale=1
```

Second solution:

> $mess->headers_as_string
>   $mess->headers_as_string( $eol )
>
> Call the as_string() method for the headers in the message.

Try

```
print $result->headers_as_string;
```

and you'll get exactly the same output as before.